# CodePipeline Task revisions are creating for ECS Fargate service, even i am not changing any task definitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, aws-fargate, ecs-taskdefinition

Is there any work around to not create tasks revision on every new deploy?
Or is there a way to remove older tasks revision from codePipeline after creating new one?

Thank you!

Comment: What is triggering your codepipeline?

Comment: Once I push to GitHub that will trigger the build

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any work around to not create tasks revision on every new deploy?

Unfortunately no, this is how the ECS Deploy Action of CodePipeline is coded.

> Or is there a way to remove older tasks revision from codePipeline after creating new one?

Unfortunately no, [1], you can only de-register it which marks it as INACTIVE and "hides" it.

[1] Deregistering Task Definition Revisions  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/deregister-task-definition.html